# how to access angular ngForm data

Tags: angular

I want to edit current user details so first I try to console log edited form data but I got an error

first I got currently logged user data into the form

```
<div *ngIf="auth.user | async; then nAuthenticated else guest">
</div>

<ng-template #nAuthenticated>
<div class="container emp-profile">
    <div *ngIf="auth.user | async as user">
        <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="nannySubmit(f)">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label>Name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <mat-form-field>
                  <input  type="text" ngModel name="name" 
                 #nameInput="ngModel" matInput placeholder= {{user.name}}>
                </mat-form-field>
             </div>
             <button type="submit" mat-raised-button color="primary" 
             [disabled]  ="f.invalid">Save Data</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</ng-template>
```

after I try to access value of input field using below code

```
export class EditProfilesComponent implements OnInit {
nanny: Nanny;
constructor(public auth: PauthService) { }

ngOnInit() {
}

nannySubmit(form: NgForm) {
    if (form.value.name != null) {
      this.nanny.name = form.value.name;
    }
console.log(this.nanny.name);
}
}
```

but after click submit button I got below error in console

'''

```
EditProfilesComponent.html:41 ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined
    at EditProfilesComponent.push../src/app/interface/edit-profiles/edit-profiles.component.ts.EditProfilesComponent.nannySubmit (edit-profiles.component.ts:31)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (EditProfilesComponent.html:41)
    at handleEvent (core.js:23008)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:24078)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:23805)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js:20457)
    at core.js:21947
    at SafeSubscriber.schedulerFn [as _next] (core.js:13516)
    at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:196)
    at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:134)
'''
```

and please tell me what is the issue I created??

Comment: You have given ```placeholder= {{user.name}}``` what does it mean?? I am unable to see anywhere ```user``` was declared with a value.. If you remove the ```placeholder= {{user.name}}``` then it works..

Comment: Yeah either remove the placeholder and see what it says, or remove the <mat-form-field> tag as that could be interferring with it.

Comment: those methods does not work

Answer (score 0):

You need add `formControlName="name"` in your input tag also check name is declared in

```
 this.ngForm= this.formBuilder.group({
            name: ['', Validators.required]
})

<input  type="text" formControlName="name" ngModel name="name" />
```

Comment: No he's doing a template based driven form not a reactive driven form.

Comment: Why you are adding ```ngModel``` inside reactive form??

Answer (score 0):

Wrong ngModel syntax so not able to read value out of ng model and define field in .ts file try this

```
<ng-template #nAuthenticated>
<div class="container emp-profile">
    <div *ngIf="auth.user | async as user">
        <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="nannySubmit()">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label>Name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <mat-form-field>
                  <input  type="text" [(ngModel)]="name" 
                 #nameInput="ngModel" matInput placeholder= {{user.name}}>
                </mat-form-field>
             </div>
             <button type="submit" mat-raised-button color="primary" 
             [disabled]  ="f.invalid">Save Data</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</ng-template>
```

In Component.ts

```
export class EditProfilesComponent implements OnInit {
nanny:any
name:any
constructor(public auth: PauthService) { }

ngOnInit() {
}

nannySubmit() {
    if (this.name != null) {
      this.nanny.name = this.name;
    }
console.log(this.nanny.name);
}
}
```

Comment: That's only if he's doing 2 way data binding. What he has there should work correctly for a simple fresh new form.

Comment: thank you but after I got another error  '''EditProfilesComponent.html:85 ERROR Error: If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or the form
      control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions.

      Example 1: <input [(ngModel)]="person.firstName" name="first">
      Example 2: <input [(ngModel)]="person.firstName" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"> '''

Comment: Okay in input tag with [(ngModel)]="name" name="anyName".It will solve the problem if not try to pass [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" within input tag